# Why does the online judge fail to accept it?

Tags: c

When I submit a code in the below given format the online judge(of Codechef ) does not accept it:

```html
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
    {
          int length,test;
          char check[26]="zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
          scanf("%d",&test);
          while(test--){
          scanf("%d",&length);
          if(length%25 != 0)
          printf("%s",check+25-(length%25));
          length/=25;
          while(length--)
                       {
                            printf("%s",check);
                       }
          printf("\n");
          }
          return 0;
}
```

However when I submit the code in the one given below it is readily accepted. Here all I've done is just made the char array from local to global. Can anyone gimme the reasons for it.

```html
#include<stdio.h>
char check[26]="zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
int main()
    {
          int length,test;
          
          scanf("%d",&test);
          while(test--){
          scanf("%d",&length);
          if(length%25 != 0)
          printf("%s",check+25-(length%25));
          length/=25;
          while(length--)
                       {
                            printf("%s",check);
                       }
          printf("\n");
          }
          return 0;
}
```

Link to the question for which it was used:

http://www.codechef.com/problems/DECSTR

Comment: try `char check[]="zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";` (26 there is no space for `\0`).

Comment: compile it on your local machine with verbose flags and see what the output is

Answer (score 5):

`check` needs 27 `char`s to store the string literal (including terminating null) you assigned to it, not 26.  Reading off the end is UB, but what's likely happening is in the global-scope version, the next byte happens to be 0, but the local-scope version, the next byte is non-zero, causing an access violation.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `check` (in either version) with "string" functions.
`check` does not have a terminating NUL byte (`'\0'`) so you invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Hint: leave off the size of the array when initializing with a string literal.

```
char check[] = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"; // compiler determines size automagically
```